# Texture doesn't wrap the same in every side of the object

Tags: texturing, uv

Surely this has been asked before, but I cannot find the question/answer.

I have the following object with a texture on it. The texture wraps correctly to some parts of it, but the sides are extremely distorted. Is there a way of correcting this?
[image: wra]

In my node wrangler, I am using the object as a texture coordinate.

Comment: Hi :). Looks as if the object isn't properly UV unwrapped. Have you tried unwrapping again?

Comment: Indeed I think it's not correctly unwrapped. It seems it has a non-uniform scale, which doesn't unwrap it correctly. But this is a problem of mine. Your solution should work if the unwrapping was good. So thank you!!

Comment: it's not clear, you're talking about unwrapping but you said that you used the Object output of the Texture Coordinate? Please share this object: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 1):

Use *Box* instead of *Flat* in your *Texture Coordinate*:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to have an effect, however, I think the root problem is that the unwrapping isn't correct. Thank you still! You literally are always the first one to answer, what a hero @moonboots !

Comment: It looks like you're using the Object output of the Texture Coordinate, from what you said, so it should work, if not please share your file. Changing the unwrap won't change anything if you don't use the UV output of the Texture Coordinate